# Error on migrating project to Angular 9 : Undecorated classes with DI migration

Tags: angular, angular9

Undecorated classes with DI migration.
As of Angular 9, it is no longer supported to use Angular DI on a class that does not have an Angular decorator.
Read more about this here: https://v9.angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes

This migration uses the Angular compiler internally and therefore projects that no longer build successfully after the update cannot run
the migration. Please ensure there are no AOT compilation errors and rerun the migration. The following project failed: src/tsconfig.app.json

Error: error TS100: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module app.module.ts. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Could not migrate all undecorated classes that use dependency
injection. Some project targets could not be analyzed due to
TypeScript program failures.

```
Migration can be rerun with: "ng update @angular/core --migrate-only migration-v9-undecorated-classes-with-di"
```

Migration completed.**

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add some more information to your question. No one will be able to help you if you just post your error message without any context.

Comment: By reading the error message I would guess you have some abstract class and some component which inherits from that class. If this is the case, simply add an angular decorator to the abstract class. But without some context its just guessing